# Unity : Why coroutine end after all Start() functions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have multiple scripts like :

- ItemDatabase
- Inventory
- GalaxyGenerator

I have Start() end/or Awake() function in each. If I put a Debug.Log() in these functions I get something like (for have the order) :

- Awake : ItemDatabase
- Awake : GalaxyGenerator
- Start : Inventory
- Start : GalaxyGenerator

**It's ok for this order**. Now I added in `ItemDatabase` a Coroutine for get Items from a database with WWW class, this is what I have :

```
void Awake(){
    Debug.Log("Awake : ItemDatabase");
    StartCoroutine(DoWWW());
}

private IEnumerator DoWWW()
{
    Debug.Log("Before www");
    www = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items");
    yield return www;

    Debug.Log("After www");

    itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject (www.text);
    ConstructItemDatabase();
}

void ConstructItemDatabase()
{
    Debug.Log("Construct ItemDatabase");
}
```

You can see differents `Debug.Log()`, and now If I check my console, I see this order :

- Awake : ItemDatabase
- Before www
- Awake : GalaxyGenerator
- Start : Inventory
- Start : GalaxyGenerator
- After www
- Construct ItemDatabase

My question is, why the end of Coroutine is after all `Start()` functions ? In my example, I need to `ConstructItemDatabase()` before `Start : GalaxyGenerator`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it takes some time to download your WWW. Your WWW-call doesn't have anything to do with the order of things, you're sending a request to a server and gets a response. If it's a big response it will take a lot of time, but either way it will take more time than it takes for Unity to go through your Awakes and Starts.

If you need the Start methods after the WWW is done, you should remove the code from Start() and put them in a method of your own, for instance `InitializeInventory()` and `InitializeGalaxyGenerator()` which you then call when your WWW is done, like you're doing with ConstructItemDatabase.

```
private IEnumerator DoWWW()
{
    Debug.Log("Before www");
    www = new WWW("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/items");
    yield return www;

    Debug.Log("After www");

    itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject (www.text);
    ConstructItemDatabase();
    InitializeInventory();
    InitializeGalaxyGenerator();
}

void ConstructItemDatabase()
{
    Debug.Log("Construct ItemDatabase");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can be a solution. So I need a script like Init.cs called first, with all my coroutines here, and all Initialize() functions for all my other scripts. So with this I stop use Start and Awake functions... Not a problem ?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what you mean and not quite sure if you understand what I mean but if you understand my answer and think your suggestion will work, try it out!